# How to serve `Docs` folder in Django which contains static html files?

Tags: django, url, documentation

I have following code structure in Django.

```
├── docs
│   └── _build
│       ├── doctrees
│       └── html
│           └── index.html
│    
├── localcoinswap
├── scripts
├── _static
├── _templates
├── tests
└── manage.py
```

Here the `docs` folder **contains static html files**. i.e *index.html*

Here are some questions regarding to problem:

1. The `docs` folder's html should be served as url `<domain>/docs/index.html` in `Django` project. How to achieve this
2. It should be restricted to User's who have `is_staff` attribute `True`.

What `urlpattern` should I use and Which `View` is useful to serve those static files (*Admin restricted*)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Add the base directory for your docs in `TEMPLATES` setting in `settings.py`.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '_templates'), "add your base directory here"],
        ...
    }
]
```

In your `urls.py`, serve the files using `TemplateView`. To further restrict the url to only the staff users, you can wrap the view in `staff_member_required` decorator.

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
...

urlpatterns += [url(r'^docs/index\.html$', staff_member_required(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')), name="index"),]
```

Make sure the file names for your templates and doc templates don't clash, else the first one evaluated according to the `DIR` list will always be considered.